# Spring 3.0 WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring-mvc

So today I've been working my way through trying to get request annotations to work properly. I have a class called HelloWorldController that contains the following code:

```
package connect.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController{

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String helloWorld(ModelMap model){

    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World");

    return "HelloWorld";
}
}
```

And dispatcher-servlet files as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="connect.controller"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="main.htm">mainViewController</prop>
                <!--<prop key="usage.htm">usageGraphController</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

   <bean name="mainViewController" 
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
         p:viewName="main" />

   </beans>
```

And finally a web.xml file that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<jsp-config>
    <taglib>

    <taglib-uri>/spring</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring-form.tld</taglib-location>

    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

The error I am receiving is:

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jCoNNECT/welcome.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Being new to Spring I have no idea where this is coming from. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like Sybase Jconnect JDBC driver... probably imported either directly or indirectly in one of you dependent JARs. Try turning on DEBUG level logging for org.springframework to see what classes are being wired up by Spring.